# Adding auto-voice feature to android music app

Tags: android

i wanna develop an android music player app that recognizes voice commands like stop, play and pause without pressing any button to receive voice i.e., app should take voice automatically when it is playing a song.. Is it possible to build such an app.. If so can anyone guide me  because i am beginner to android app development.. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd say that it is generally bad idea to recognize sound while you are playing sound. The most common issue that the song itself may contain your keywords, which will influence playback.

Comment: Do u say that speakers and microphone don't work simultaneously??? @Vlad matvienko

Comment: I didn't say that, but if there is a word "Stop" in the song, it will recognize it as command, and stop itself. That's why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Ohhh okk got ur doubt :)